# Is there a way to disable the "Please log in to continue" message in a Facebook Canvas app?

Tags: facebook

when you visit a Facebook Canvas app (such as http://apps.facebook.com/branchout/) and you are not logged in to Facebook, you will get the "Please log in to continue." dialog every 10 seconds or so.

I am planning to develop a Facebook Canvas app that does not ask for user authentication/ app authorization upfront (I don't want to scare users away), but I do not want to go that way if I cannot stop that dialog.

Is there any way to disable it, or should I rather ask for authentication/ authorization upfront? Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is Facebook trying to refresh their ads. I've done a few apps that don't require authentication or login until specific actions are performed. If you are not logged into Facebook, then that prompt comes up. The only action I am performing is calling getLoginStatus on load. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is any way around it. When I load my app directly (not in a Facebook iframe), the prompt doesn't come up.

Answer (score 2):

Brent is right, it's just a bug. The what's-going-on pane on the right hand side tries to reload, and gets confused when there's no user logged in. Don't worry about it, it should be gone soon :-)